# send form data as email in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I send form data to a preset email address in Magento (like how the contact form works) ?

EDIT : What I'm trying is to have a form in a static block which when submitted, sends the form data to an email address (admin@mystore.com)

Comment: have you tried writing a phtml template an send email via mail()?

Comment: @Rito - not sure how that's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not sure what you need. Heres an example for a custom static formular. All you need is to create a phtml template and this add into a cms page.

in RTE:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="myformular" template="contacts/myformular.phtml"}}
```

or in xml layout

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="myformular" template="contacts/myformular.phtml" />
</reference>
```

inside that phtml file you can design your mail with plain php
[How to send email with php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Send mail:
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
    ->setToName('Prajapati jignesh')
    ->setToEmail('jignesh@gmail.com')
    ->setBody('Message body')
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->setType('text'); // or html
try{
    $mail->send();
}
catch(Exception $error)
{
    // Could not send email
}
```